# java style database connection on android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
package com.example.wgame;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import android.util.Log;


public class connDB {
Connection conn = null;
public static Connection connectDB() {
    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:wSdict.sqlite");
        Log.v("DBCon","Connected!");
        return conn;
    }catch (Exception r) {
        Log.e("DBCon","Not Connected");

        return null;
    }
}

}
```

is it possible to connect my sqlite database file this way on android and not having to use SQLiteHelper class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not. Android uses sqlite3, and can only be accessed by the API provided by android. There is no third party library or any helper class to achieve this.

refer this link for more info.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary.html

Comment: ok! but how do i use a ready-made database (wSdict.sqlite) on android ?

Comment: These links should help you. http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/  and   http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/importing-sqlite-db-into-android-project-t52616.html